# I don't know how to solve this error [client is not defined]

Tags: discord.js

ReferenceError: client is not defined
    at Object. (C:\Users\Utilizador\Desktop\securitybot\bot.js:3:1)

```
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:30)

at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1177:10)

at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:32)

at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:900:14)

at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
```

PS C:\Users\Utilizador\Desktop\securitybot>

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you give us your code? We can't help you otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below to the top of the file.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
```

If you have already defined discord.js don't define it again.

---

Also, it could be a *small* chance that your client variable is named `bot`, some people use `bot` instead of `client` as the variable. Check at the top of your file and see if you have a different name.